# Django: multiple dynamic comboboxes

Tags: django, combobox, widget

Does anyone know how to link two ComboBoxes which are generated from a form in a way that makes the second ComboBox dependent on the first one?

Every time the user would change the selection in ComboBox #1, the options in ComboBox #2 would change to a predefined list of options. The potential options for both comboboxes are fixed at time of generating the html file.

Thanks for any help.

Cheers,
Max.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to get selected options of #1, process the list and change #2 according to it.

With jQuery it's not that hard.

Use

```
$('select#id_of_1 option:selected').val();
```

to get the list of selected options and process this list afterwards.

Comment: Afaik nothing like that is builtin. You have to write your own script to do that.